# Python pyspark error

Tags: python, pyspark

I am using Pyspark to create a dataframe but come up against an error from the get go.

I am using the following code to create the dataframe using data from the examples folder:

```
df = spark.read.load(`c:/spark/examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet`)
```

This generates the following extensive error message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
16/09/09 15:41:51 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/09/09 15:41:51 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hiv
e.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClien
t
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:c:/Spark/
bin/spark-warehouse
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:c:/Spark/bin/spark-warehouse
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
        ... 58 more
16/09/09 15:41:51 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 147, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "c:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 933, in __call__
  File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Sessio
nHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClien
t
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:c:/Spark/
bin/spark-warehouse
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:c:/Spark/bin/spark-warehouse
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
        ... 55 more
```

I think a cause may be this line:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:c:/Spark/bin/spark-warehouse
```

I'm not confident how to address this so any assistance is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the Spark installation.I installed locally. I created rdd’s & everything went fine until I wanted to create a Spark DataFrame from the rdds ... big errors.

The issue was with the pre-built Spark version: spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7

I Removed spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 and downloaded and installed spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6
Used pip install py4j rather than unzipping and using the version shipped with the pre-built Spark

I can now create the DataFrame

The outcome I think is two fold:
1.  Use  spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6 if installing on Windows7 and want to use Spark DataFrames
2.  SparkSession is not available – only came out with Spark 2, have to use SQLContext … oh well!

regards